# Poor review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Just came across another poor review audit, IMO:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7689727

I chose to close with "Unclear what you're asking". There's no direct question in there, and indirectly there is only "any idea would be gratefully received". But the system says I should vote "Looks good".

There are also no upvoted answers. The only reason that the system seems to like this question is the 5 upvotes it got. Which seems suspicious in itself, given the low quality of the question.

Comment: I don't agree. There are a couple of things in the text that might be the real question ("Writing an extractor", "Scraping the docs", "Parsing class files") that seem to have a tenuous relation with the title. Of *what* is the question looking for a Minimum API version of, etc. I'm looking at the "Low quality" queue at that point so I have to make a decision based on what's in the question at that point, and making this an acceptable question would require multiple clarifications from the OP.